# Configure Blazor WebAssembly with active directory federation services (AD FS)

Tags: active-directory, blazor, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, adfs

I'm trying to authenticate my frontend Blazor WASM SPA through an on-premise company ADFS. But I'm quite lost, does anyone know how to set this up or point me to some resources?

I can only find solutions using Azure Active Directory which I'm trying to avoid since we already have a local AD.

My tech stack is:

- Blazor WebAssembly
- ASP.NET Core 6 Web Api

Answer (score 0):

Oke I figured it out using [Blazor WebAssembly with the Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code).

```cs
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.ClientId = "client-id-from-adfs";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authority = "https://<adfs-server>/adfs/";
    options.ProviderOptions.RedirectUri = "https://localhost:xxxx/login-callback";
});
```

I also started Chrome with `chrome --incognito --ignore-certificate-errors` to avoid problems with the (development) SSL certificate.

**Edit:**

I still had some issues with the previous solution, for example I couldn't retrieve my token through the `IAccessTokenProvider` because it wasn't set properly.

So I used the MSAL library ([Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal)) which also works through OAuth2/OpenID Connect while still following the instructions from [Blazor WebAssembly with the Authentication library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code).

Example:

```cs
// Program.cs

// Instead of .AddOidcAuthentication()
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.Authority = "https://<adfs-server>/adfs/";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ClientId = "client-id-from-adfs";
    options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ValidateAuthority = true;
});
```