# Blazor WASM Not Redirecting to Login Page

Tags: authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor and trying to authenticate using oidc. I am trying to use the instructions from [Secure an ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly standalone app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) to set it up.

Here is what I want the app to do (this, I think is a 'normal' app flow):

1. Start app
2. Be redirected to a login page (this login page is not within my app)
3. After login redirect back to app

I must be missing something simple.  When I try to run the app I see this error in the Browser Console errors:

Refused to display 'https://xxxx.yyyy.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

In the response headers, I see this:

X-Frame-Options: **DENY**

X-MS-Forwarded-Status-Code: 500

And in the request headers:

**Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe**
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

I am trying to emulate an existing, working Angular app and in that app headers, I see this in the header

**Sec-Fetch-Dest: document**

Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate

Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site

I'm not sure if that difference in the header is the difference or not but it's the only thing I see.  Looking for advice on how to get this login flow working?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my scenario - Blazor Webassembly to ADFS is not supported. After days of banging my head, I found this: [BLAZOR WASM - ADFS - OIDC - Documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40331) indicating this is not a supported scenario.

I then found article which pointed me in the correct direction [Configure Blazor WASM with ADFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451623/configure-blazor-webassembly-with-active-directory-federation-services-ad-fs)

Turns out the MSAL provider seems to work fine for this scenario:

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options => {
// Configure your authentication provider options here.
options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.Authority = "https://xxx.yyyy.com/adfs";
options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ClientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx";
options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.NavigateToLoginRequestUrl = true;
options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
```

});